# Saving web pages in Firefox as text or RTF files that preserve basic formatting and positioning

Tags: firefox, text-formatting, webpage, rtf, textfiles

Is it possible, within Firefox, to save pages containing text while keeping the ***basic*** formatting and positioning, but not saving any executable code (JavaScript)?

It doesn't need to be perfect, just a close approximation.

I need the text to be searchable, so taking a screenshot will not suffice.

Answers that apply to Windows are preferred.

What I've tried:

1. Copy and paste into notepad.
   *Result:* Lost all text formatting and positioning (as expected).
2. Copy and paste into OpenOffice, LibreOffice, and Wordpad.
   *Result:* Did not maintain sufficient text positioning.  Specifically, left and right justified text all became left-justified.
3. Save as text file from within Firefox.
   *Result:* Same as #1.
4. Save as HTML-only file from within Firefox.
   *Result:* Same as #2.
5. Save as HTML-complete file from within Firefox.
   *Result:* For whatever reason, Firefox reports a failure for many pages, probably due to how the pages are served via HTTPS.

My current workaround is a PITA.  I download the HTML of the page and any CSS.  Then I manually edit each HTML file to point to the local copy of the CSS files.  Finally, I remove all JavaScript references.  This takes a fair amount of time and effort, and results in a dependency on CSS files, instead of a single clean text or RTF file.

I have considered the [Mozilla Archive Format extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/), but I think it always saves all the JavaScript in the archive.  I prefer a flat text or RTF (rich text) file with no dependencies and definitely no JavaScript.

Comment: I believe the usual process is to do manual work.  Sorry.  My guess is you won't see a very satisfying answer.  However, how do you remove all JavaScript references?  That ought to be fairly automate-able.  For instance, replace <SCRIPT with <SCRdisabled (and /SCRIPT)...  that would make the HTML technically invalid, but probably render just fine/acceptably.

Comment: @TOOGAM Yes, I make edits like that or just edit out all `<SCRIPT>` and `</SCRIPT>` tags.  I don't like having to keep all the CSS files around, so I will sometimes copy and paste the important CSS styles into the HTML to apply them directly.  It's rather time consuming.  Cutting and pasting into a word processor comes so close, but losing the left and right-justification causes the loss of important positioning, especially for text transcriptions.

Comment: Do ya hafta use Firefox?  Can you use another web scraper, like cURL?

Comment: @TOOGAM Good question.  I strongly prefer Firefox, but it doesn't have to use it.  Just to clarify, I only have this need for occasional web pages (typically 1-5 per day), and I just need the text on the single page (I don't need to scrape an entire site or anything).  The pages are typically served via HTTPS.  I'm usually at a Windows box when I need to do this.